# Elasticsearch: get all the messages (more than 10000) in python3

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I have ElasticSearch 5.2 and using python 3.5 to retrieve the messages (only get no updates).
The search criteria which I have has total messages more than 10000.

I explored the scroll, however the time taken is too long.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'my-host', 'port': 9200}])
sBody = """
{
   "query": {
         "bool": {
             "must": {
                 "match": {
                         "header.batchId": "batch_id_1"
                }
             }
         }
     }
 }
 """
response = es.search(
      index='index.name',
      body=sBody,
      scroll='2m'
  )

scroll_id = response['_scroll_id']
out = []
while len(response['hits']['hits']):
      response = es.scroll(scroll_id=scroll_id, scroll='2m')
      out += response

print(out)
```

Total message in above example is ~166500.

When I run simply without the scroll, and give size = 10000, I see that the messages are retired fairly quicker.
Of course they are not all the messages, which is not useful to me, but the difference is not much between 10000 and total messages, but the time taken is big.

Next I tried to use elasticsearch_dsl

Additional code:

```
    from elasticsearch_dsl import Search, Q
    from elasticsearch_dsl.query import Match

    qx = Q({'bool': {'must': { 'match' : {'header.batchId' : 'batch_id_1'}}}})
    s = Search(using=es, index="index.name").query(qx)
    response = s.execute()
    print('Total %d hits found.' % response.hits.total)
```

The above code gives correct total number of messages.

But when I try to iterate over the response, it gives only default 10 messages.

So what additional I have to do here to fetch all the messages?

Is there any other better way?

Answer (score 0):

Try by passing the size parameter to your es.search() call.

Please read the [Documentation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)

size – Number of hits to return (default: 10)

For example: `es.search(index=logs_index, body=my_query, size=1000)`

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'my-host', 'port': 9200}])
doc = {
    'size' : 10000,
    'query': {
        'match_all' : {}
    }
}

res = es.search(index='index.name', body=sBody, scroll='2m')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is rather big (let's say more than just 10k) you will have to use eg. Scroll feature. If that's not the case you can use the From/Size options only but remember that from+size cannot exceed index.max_result_window parameter though. See more: [From/Size | ES 7.x](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html)